# Status of locality of perfectoidness for uniform rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $k$ be a perfectoid field of zero characteristic. Recall that a Tate $k$-algebra is called uniform if the set of power-bounded elements is bounded. Let $(A, A^+)$ be a uniform complete affinoid $k$-algebra such that $Spa(A, A^+)$ has a cover by rational subsets which are perfectoid. Is $A$ perfectoid?

Comment: This is an open problem, even if you assume that $A$ is sheafy too.